# Как избавиться от sudo

Tags: консоль, webpack, npm, macos, sudo

всем привет! я новичок в macOS и в целом мало и плохо работаю с командной строкой. по-началу все было ок, но спустя некоторое время терминал начал требовать вводить sudo перед любой установкой любой библиотеки. ну просит и просит. теперь же я не могу запускать даже обычные проекты на реакте: [image: пример ошибки]

я подозреваю, что у меня(пользователя и администратора компа) нет прав на запись в папках. если перейти по адресу папки в котором есть ошибка, и дам себе доступ на запись, то ошибка пропадает.
но например сохранять код я так же не могу[image: пример ошибки2]

гуглил похожие ошибки и советуют просто переустанавливать и/или давать через команды еще доступы(мне не помогает). можно ли как-то получить полный доступ над компьютером или хотя бы избавиться от судо и чтобы комп понимал, что я могу записывать и читать все, что хочу(хотя бы в проектах, которые сам создал).

*боюсь что у меня все меньше доступа к компьютеру с каждым днем и завтра он обретет полную самостоятельность и он убежит(шутка)*

Comment: `sudo chmod -Rv sharkavli:sharkavli /Users/sharkavli/dev`

Comment: (возможно, имеет смысл выполнить эту команду для всего домашнего каталога целиком, но так как я не знаю, что и зачем там лежит, то от такого предложения воздержусь)

Comment: вопрос с невозможностью сохранения изменения в файлах с кодом я решил дав доступ всей папке dev с опцией "применить ко всем вложенным объектам". а вот ответ andreymal мне не помог, почему-то. я бы уточнил у него, но у меня нет кнопки ответить именно ему почему-то.

Comment: @sharkavli, для комментария, предназначенного конкретному юзеру, начинайте его с `@nickname`

Comment: @avp понял, спасибо